# Soft keyboard close animation causes lag to other animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-softkeyboard

I have a Toast which is being launched from `EditText` and its `onFocusChangeListener`.
Basically, when the view loses focus, soft keyboard is being hidden and Toast is being shown.

The Toast itself has a slide down animation.

The problem is, that this animation is lagging/stuttering and I've noticed that the reason for this, is **simultaneous soft keyboard closing animation.**

**It seems that the lag is caused by closing the keyboard and doing slide down animation at the same time.**

I was able to solve this issue by delaying showing of the toast:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(showToast(), 200L)
```

But this is a hacky solution, are there any other ways how can I improve this to fix the lagging when keyboard and toast animations are launched at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
            // your softkeyboard closing code
            android.os.Message alertMessage = new android.os.Message();
            alertMessage.what = 1;
            handle.sendMessage(alertMessage);
```

and show the toast in the handler like this in this code below

Handler handle = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

```
        if (msg.what == 1) {

           // your toast animation code

        }

        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }


};
```